# How to make a python wsgi script return to php?

Tags: php, python, wsgi

I have a php script that passes a value to an http://something..../wsgi.py page which computes and returns a value.

I do not want to display this .py page. Instead, I want to call another php page along with the value computed by the python page.

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant solution to this problem would be to return an HTTP redirect response from the Python script. With such a solution, your browser doesn't need to load and display the HTML from the Python script, making the redirection more transparent to the user.

A code snippet creating HTTP redirect with WSGI follows:

```
def redirector_app(environ, start_response):
   param = '' # Set the parameter you want to pass here
   start_response('301 Redirect', [('Location', 'http:/yourphpscript.com/?param=%s' % param),])
   # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If a `<form>` is unacceptable, you can use an HTML `<link>` or `<img>` tag in order to make the browser request the indicated URL.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer or add your own if you're not satisfied with this one.

Comment: Yes. If you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as your preferred solution.